# JSON Convertir 1 array en multiples arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bucle-for, jsonobject

Tengo un JSON array que cuenta con el Parametro Nombre y el Parametro Valor. Este array se repite en múltiples ocasiones el mismo Nombre:

```
{
  [
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:53},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:12},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:22},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:89},
    {Nombre: "PEREZIN", Valor:11}

  ]
}
```

Como puedo con el JSON de arriba, N cantidad de JSON arrays, donde cada array no se repita el Nombre en mas de 1 vez?

EJEMPLO:

```
{
  [
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "PEREZIN", Valor:11}
  ],
  [
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:12},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:89},
  ],
  [
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:53},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:22},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arreglo = 
  [
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "LIGIA MARIA", Valor:53},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:32},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:12},
    {Nombre: "MARY I", Valor:22},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:55},
    {Nombre: "PERLA NEGRA", Valor:89},
    {Nombre: "PEREZIN", Valor:11}

  ];
  
var numeroGrupos = 0;

//calcular el total de grupos a crear
arreglo.reduce( (a,c) => {

 if(c.Nombre === a.Nombre){
    c.repite = a.repite + 1;
 }else{
    if(numeroGrupos < a.repite) numeroGrupos = a.repite;
    c.repite = 1;
 }
 
 return c;

});



// variable para agrupar  los nuevos grupos
var arreglosAgrupados = [];
//se inicializa la variable un arreglo por grupo
for(i = 0; i < numeroGrupos; i++){
 arreglosAgrupados.push([]);
}

//funcion para guardar un objeto en el grupo que le corresponde
function guardarEnGrupo(elemento){
 
 agregado = false;
 //se recorren todos los grupos
 arreglosAgrupados.forEach( a => {
   if(!agregado)
   //si el objeto no ha sido agregado en ningun grupo se agrega
   if(a.findIndex(e => e.Nombre == elemento.Nombre) == -1){
        a.push(elemento);
        //se cambia el valor para que el objeto no se agregue
        //en otro grupo
        agregado = true;
   }
 });
}
//se recorren los objetos y se asignan en sus grupos
arreglo.forEach( e => {
 delete e.repite;
 guardarEnGrupo(e);
});

console.log(arreglosAgrupados);
```

Comment: Excelente!, justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias amigo